# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dotnet

Tags: python, .net, installation, pip, python-3.7

I tried to pip install the package dotnet for python 3.7.5 and got the following error:

```
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dotnet (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for dotnet
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found out the package dotnet only supports python 3.6 and python 2.7, [see official release doc here.](https://pypi.org/project/dotnet/#files) I managed to convert the project I am working on to python 3.6 and successfully pip install dotnet. In general it's a good practice to look at the package documentation to see which version it supports.