# ERROR: No matching distribution found for dotnet

Tags: python, .net, python-3.9

Originally using `python 2.7`.
Now using `python 3.9`.

Opening the existing file gives this error message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dotnet (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for dotnet
```

Basic code that would produce this error:

```
import dotnet
print('dotnet is imported')
```

An attempt has been made here:
[ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dotnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64504234/error-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-dotnet)

The solution in the above suggests that there is no support for `3.9` as per version support.

There is a package here: https://pypi.org/project/pythonnet/ but i have not tried this yet.

So there question is, are there alternative methods for getting the same working ?

Comment: Well, if you look at the PyPI link in the other question, it only shows wheels for 2.7 and 3.6, with no source `.tar.gz` file. The BitBucket link is broken, and after a (very) brief search I didn't find anything authoritative on Github, so clearly the package is dead. Try `pythonnet` and see if it works for your needs. There's really nothing else to say.

Comment: Thanks. That is a useful comment. I  presume the question should be does pythonnet (`python 3.9`) replace dotnet (`python 2.7`) ?

Comment: Unfortunately, PyPI only has `pythonnet` wheels up to version 3.8. I just tried to build it with 3.9, and it died with a bunch of compiler errors. I have a pretty well-stocked development environment, so I can't imagine that you'll have any more luck. If you really need this functionality, I'd recommend downgrading to 3.8, and/or lobbying [on Github](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet) for a 3.9 wheel release on PyPI.

Comment: Would you like to add this as a solution as it is the most complete solution. If not, i will add it. Thanks.

Comment: sure, when I get a chance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [`dotnet` PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/dotnet/) under "Download files", you'll see that they only have wheels for Python 2.7 and 3.6. There isn't even a link to a source code `.zip` or `.tar.gz` file. The module's [BitBucket link](https://bitbucket.org/pydotnet/pydotnet) is dead. I found [this](https://github.com/tr8dr/.Net-Bridge/tree/master/src/Python/pyDotNet) on Github, but I didn't try to build it, as I don't have Visual Studio installed. YMMV.

As far as [`pythonnet`](https://pypi.org/project/pythonnet/) is concerned, they currently only have [wheels](https://pypi.org/project/pythonnet/#files) up to Python 3.8, even though the 3.0 development branch builds successfully on [Appveyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/pythonnet/pythonnet/branch/master) with 3.9. You can try grabbing a wheel from [here](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/pythonnet/pythonnet/branch/master/job/vlcyuh801tsggwvh/artifacts) (temporary link, will be deleted after 1 month per Appveyor's [policy](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/packaging-artifacts/#artifacts-retention-policy)). I have not tried this path, so again YMMV. Downgrading to Python 3.8 is always an option.

Finally, you can [open an issue](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues) or find an existing one to lobby for a 3.9 wheel release.

Comment: Marked as the default answer, given there is no alternative solution. Downgrade to 3.8 is not viable, but might suit others. Lobby for 3.9 wheel release is alternative.

Comment: issue is opened here:   https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/1506